# How to hide toggle (div) when clicking anywhere on the page

Tags: jquery, toggle

I used `toggle` to Hide/Show `DIV`

HTML

```
<div class="wrap">

  <h1 id="selectBox">Service you&#39;re interested in</h1>

  <div class="selectBox">
    <div class="selectBoxWrap">

      <ul class="selectBoxContent">
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="#" value="New Web Site" /> <span class="innerPageSelect">Website Design and Development</span></li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="#" value="New Web Site" /> <span>Website Maintenance</span></li>
        <li class="other">
          <p>
            <label for="other">Other</label><br />
        <input type="text" name="other" value="" id="other" />
          </p>
         </li>
       </ul> 

      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JQUERY

```
$(function() {

            $('#selectBox').click(function() {
        $('.selectBoxContent').slideToggle('fast');
        return false;

    });
        });
```

i want, hide toggle div when clicking anywhere on the page after selecting services by checking the `checkbox` or input something in the `textbox`.

this is my fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jhunlio/TEyHC/2/)

your comment and suggestion is appreciated

thank you in advance!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this

```
$(document).click(function() {
 $('.selectBoxContent').slideUp('fast');
});

$(".selectBoxContent").click(function(e) { // Wont toggle on any click in the div
e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TEyHC/8/)

Comment: your idea is much closer in what it should, but it make the whole page toggle.

Comment: Change the document click from slideToggle to slideUp          
     $('.selectBoxContent').slideUp('fast');

Comment: i change this part `$('.selectBoxContent').slideToggle('fast');` to `$('.selectBoxContent').slideUp('fast');` as you suggest but the whole thing is not working.

Comment: thank you so much for the help and time that you give to my question.

Comment: by the way if you don't mind what is the explanation bihind this!

Comment: event.stopPropagation prevents further propagation of the current event up the DOM and triggering the click event of the document. [Here](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html) is a good article explaining this in detail

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on("click", function(e) {
        if ($(e.srcElement).closest('.selectBoxWrap').length) return;
        if ($('.selectBoxContent').is(":visible")) $('.selectBoxContent').slideToggle('fast');
    });
    $('#selectBox').on("click", function(e) {
        if ($(e.srcElement).closest('.selectBoxWrap').length) return;
        $('.selectBoxContent').slideToggle('fast');
        return false;
    });
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TEyHC/9/

Comment: thank's for the suggestion it make little closer what i need to achieve by the way this is the way that i want [here](http://dropdown-check-list.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/dropdownchecklist.html#s1)

Answer (score 0):

You can bind a click event handler to the html tag:

```
$(function() {
    $('#selectBox').click(function() {
        $('html').click(function() {
            $(this).unbind('click');
            $('.selectBoxContent').slideToggle('fast');
        });
        $('.selectBoxContent').slideToggle('fast');
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: why are you using `$(this).unbind('click');`?

Comment: You only want the html tags click event to close the menu if it is open. If the event is not unbound then clicking anywhere on the page will open the menu. So it depends on how you want your menu to work.

Comment: hi @tantricllama your idea is closer in what i want to achieve but i need first to select two or more services before closing the toggle by the way.. thank you so much in giving time to my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this

```
 $('html').click(function() {
       $('.selectBoxContent').slideToggle('fast');
  });
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TEyHC/3/)

Comment: This makes the whole page toggle the menu, no?

Comment: I agree with @FloydPink this make the whole page toggle.